# I am not able to change the state when I send an input by using a form

Tags: reactjs

I tried to implement a simple form that receives an input and triggers a function addStakes. When I submit the input the function does not do anything and the console.log show just nothing. I am a bit confused about why is not working.Can anyone help me in fixing this error? Thanks

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Stake() {
    const [stakes, setStakes] = useState([]);

    const addStake = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const el = e.target.value;
        if (!stakes) {
            setStakes([...stakes, el]);
            console.log(stakes)
        }
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={addStake}>
                <input
                    style={{
                        marginLeft: "40px",
                        width: "50px"
                    }}
                    type="text"
                    name="stake"
                    required
                />
            </form>

        </div>
    );
}

export default Stake;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot `console.log(stakes)` right after setting it. Because `setState` is asynchronous. Instead, you can access the updated state variable when the component re-renders, therefore inside the `useEffect` hook.

```
import {useEffect} from 'react';
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(stakes);
})
```

or alternatively, you can log the stakes anywhere inside the component, but `useEffect` will be where you would want to use the updated state variables.

More info on the React lifecycle can be read [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

#### A potential logical error

Before adding to the `stakes` you check `if(!stakes)`. Therefore your stakes variable will be set only once. Try removing that condition, if you are going to update your `stakes` variable. And `stakes` will always be *truthy* since it is initialized to `[]`

#### Another problem with the form

The function `addStake` is not getting the value of the input, since the event `e` does not contain the `input` component's value. You can try a seperate state variable for that. See the [working example on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-mirzakhani-ed4ud) (You can get rid of the button of course)

Comment: I removed the if condition but now when I console.log displays an array with undefined

Comment: I see the problem now, your e.target.value is undefined. I will link a working `codesandbox` here

Comment: Do you mind if I ask you to explain me why you coded it like that?Thanks

Comment: The problem was, you attach the function `addStakes` to `onSubmit`. And the event `e` comes with it doesn't have the target value of the `input`. Try to console.log(e) inside the addStakes function. Therefore, you need a way to store the input value. I changed the `input` to a controlled one. Each time I change the input, I update the state variable `singleStake`. And each time I add the stake to the array, I reset it. Just book keeping if you will :)

Comment: Wow! Thank you! Anyway I got another problem, might post another question in few mins but you're great :)